# Android Studio: Gradle build finished with 251 errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle, build-error

I have this Android project that I was successfully running on Android Studio. The problem is: ever since I have reinstalled my Windows, ironically, after I had installed everything, including Android Studio and other support libs, the project has never built successfully.

The error log is:

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
D:\Users\Andy\AndroidstudioProjects\myapp\myapp\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v17\values-v17.xml
Error:(4, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(8, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
Error:(14, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(20, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(21, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(25, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(24, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(28, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(31, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(34, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
Error:(38, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
Error:(37, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(41, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(45, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(44, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(49, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(48, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(4, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(8, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
Error:(14, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(20, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(21, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(25, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(24, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(28, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(31, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(34, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
Error:(38, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
Error:(37, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(41, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(45, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(44, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(49, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(48, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
D:\Users\Andy\AndroidstudioProjects\myapp\myapp\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(212) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(214) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(222) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(232) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(254) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
Error:(172) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(185) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(6) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(8) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(10) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(23) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(27) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(29) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(30) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(49) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(51) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(54) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(55) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(57) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(102, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(106, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(104, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(105, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(103, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(100, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(101, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(109, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(149, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(153, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(151, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(152, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(150, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(147, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(148, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(156, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(159, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(161) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(163) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(165) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(167) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(170) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(175) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(176) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(177) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(180) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(181) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(182) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(183) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(184) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(188) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ImageButton'.
Error:(189) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(191) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(193) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(195) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(199, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(201) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(203) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(204) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(206) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(210, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(216) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(217) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.SeekBar'.
Error:(218) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(219) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(220) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(246, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(250, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(248, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(249, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(247, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(244, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(245, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(212) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(214) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(222) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(232) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(254) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
Error:(172) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(185) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(6) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(8) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(10) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(23) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(27) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(29) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(30) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(49) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(51) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(54) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(55) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(57) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(102, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(106, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(104, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(105, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(103, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(100, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(101, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(109, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(149, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(153, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(151, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(152, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(150, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(147, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(148, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(156, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(159, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(161) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(163) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(165) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(167) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(170) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(175) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(176) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(177) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
.
.  
.
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/AndroidViewAnimations-1.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/kenburnsview-1.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/TapForTap.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV3-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.1.jar')
}
```

If anyone has any idea why the build suddenly went crazy and any clues how to fix it?

I have not changed anything before and after Windows re-installation.

Comment: Your method of importing libraries via jar files is pretty unconventional...

Comment: Writing an app in assembler could work but is unconventional. I'd stick to pulling the dependencies from a remote repository like Maven Central to make updating them easier. If you're worried about it going offline you can put a proxy like Nexus in front of it to get a local backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `compileSdkVersion` to the latest (presently, 25) and your `buildToolsVersion` to match (presently, 25.0.2). Then, replace the `+` on your dependency versions with actual version numbers:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

In the case of `support-v4`, that would be 25.1.1 at the moment. I forget off the top of my head what the latest `play-services` version number is.

As it stands, you are pulling in a newer `support-v4` than your `compileSdkVersion` works with.

Comment: if play-services the latest version is 10.2.0 then only a few errors remained after your suggestions.

myproject\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(460) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(347) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(460) Attribute "background" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(347) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':amazingKickandScream:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt